# GenerateReference error when building C# among us mod

Tags: c#

I started with Among Us mod making a few days ago, I set everything up and followed the instructions listed on this page (https://docs.reactor.gg/docs/) and everything worked. I could build my mods and it would work as intended. 2 days ago, out of the blue all of my imports (like the UnityEngine import and other external imports) were throwing 'does not exist in this current context errors' The root of this (I found) was this:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB4018 The "GenerateReferences" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Cecil, Version=0.11.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50cebf1cceb9d05e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Mono.Cecil, Version=0.11.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50cebf1cceb9d05e'
at Il2CppDumper.DummyAssemblyExporter.Export(Il2CppExecutor il2CppExecutor, String outputDir, Boolean addToken)
at Il2CppDumper.Il2CppDumper.PerformDump(String gameAssemblyPath, String metadataDatPath, String outputDirectoryPath, Config config, Action`1 reportProgressAction)
at Reactor.OxygenFilter.MSBuild.GenerateReferences.Execute() in /home/js6pak/Development/AmongUs/Reactor.OxygenFilter/Reactor.OxygenFilter.MSBuild/GenerateReferences.cs:line 56
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].REDACTED.REDACTED]
```

I have tried reimporting, and redoing everything from scratch (like redownloading BepinEx, Reactor, Among Us) and have also tried building a fresh project, but even new projects don't seem to build. Is there something wrong on my part?

Comment: I think you have a compile error so a dll (probably another project) is not getting generated.  Do you have more than one project?

Comment: I don't have more than one project, the weird this is that this error came up out of the blue

Comment: Error indicates code is not build.  Try removing all files from the bin folder.  Sometimes the files get locked.  Often there are files in the bin folder called "Host" that aren't getting removed which are used as locks.

Comment: I've tried removing the bin and the obj folders, but to no avail

Comment: Did you try rebooting the machine?  The original project may not of shutdown everything.  Yo may want to look at Task Manager to see if previous process is still open.  Make sure you aren't running any code that should only be run once like creating a new database (you already have a database).

Comment: I have tried this as well

Comment: The error says : GenerateReferences.cs:line 56.  What is line 56?  Also check the value of  gameAssemblyPath to make sure you can read and write the files in the folder.

Comment: GenerateReferences.cs is from the Nuclear framework, and where would someone get the value of gameAssemblyPath (by the way, thank you so much for helping me out)

Comment: Put a break point on line 56 and then hover over the variable.

Comment: Reactor is an open source project hosted on github. You should make an issue in github for this error so the repo contributors know about it. I believe this is the [property file](https://github.com/NuclearPowered/Reactor.OxygenFilter/blob/master/Reactor.OxygenFilter.MSBuild/Reactor.OxygenFilter.MSBuild.TargetFramework.props) in question where it fails on line 56.

Comment: I'm so sorry for not updating this post, I have fixed this issue a while back. I had made an issue on the GitHub page and it was resolved. Turns out I just had to downgrade my Among Us version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had to downgrade my Among Us version. The way I downgraded the version was using Docker, but I suppose any other way could work.